# How can I add items to my self created control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a user control in WinForms, which I would like to select in another application from the toolbox.

My question now:
How can I get it to add additional elements to the properties window of this custom control, e.g. labels which are then drawn in the design window.

For example:  with the ListView I can create additional ListViewItems in the design window and they will be displayed directly.

I would like to have exactly this feature for my self created Control, with the difference that they are not ListViewItems but e.g. labels.

Here is a ScreenShot, which should clarify what I mean exactly:

[image]

in this picture you can see how I selected the ListView and when I click on Items I get a new window where I can add ListViewItems to this control.

I would have liked to have this feature for my self created control.

Comment: This may be interesting for you: [Walkthrough: Create a control that takes advantage of design-time features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-a-wf-control-design-time-features)

Comment: You, sir, have made my day. 
 just have to know what to look for, thank you very much. If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft offers a Walk-Through about this topic:

[Walkthrough: Create a control that takes advantage of design-time features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-a-wf-control-design-time-features)

The gist of it is: (shorted from Link above)

> To define a custom control and its custom designer
>
> 1. Open the MarqueeControl source file in the Code Editor. At the top of the file, import the following namespaces: ... (see link)
> 2. Add the DesignerAttribute to the MarqueeControl class declaration. This associates the custom control with its designer.
> 3. Open the MarqueeControlRootDesigner source file in the Code Editor. At the top of the file, import the following namespaces: ... (see link)
> 4. Change the declaration of MarqueeControlRootDesigner to inherit from the DocumentDesigner class. Apply the ToolboxItemFilterAttribute to specify the designer interaction with the Toolbox.
> 5. Define the constructor for the MarqueeControlRootDesigner class. Insert a WriteLine statement in the constructor body. This will be useful for debugging.